# How to make my app pop up when I detect a certain event?

Tags: android, android-permissions

*Note: This was originally posted on [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239539/how-to-make-my-app-pop-up-when-i-detect-a-certain-event) but is now moved here because it was found to be off-topic there*

Kaspersky Safe Kids, a parental control app, has a feature where it would pop up every time it detects an event that the child was not meant to do (open an app, open anything related to its settings, search something banned on Google and Youtube -- interestingly enough, it doesn't work on other Chromium-based browsers). I've been trying to figure out how it can detect events for my own app, but the usual culprits like the permissions GET_TASKS and READ_LOGS are depreciated (I'm trying to target, and Kaspersky works on, Android 10+). For the actual overlay, I thought it used SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, but in my own experiments in an emulator, when I revoked that permission, it was still able to pop up. So, how does it work, and what permissions do they (and I'm guessing other similar control and productivity apps) work?

The app is Device Admin, so that may play a role, but looking at the [permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#policies) a Device Admin has, none of them look like the permissions Kaspersky has.

**EDIT:** In the comments, Mike M. noted that the app uses Accessibility Services (don't know how I missed that), which makes sense as Accessibility allows you to do quite a lot, including showing your own UI. Coincidentally, a review on the app itself states that the process ends at random times (not sure which process though), probably because it was not whitelisted. I then took a look at its permissions and this one stood out: `android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`. This permission allows it to be whitelisted, so that power saving modes don't kill the background processes. For the accessibility itself, `android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE` is the permission used to grant it (for the record, you must use `adb shell appops set com.kaspersky.safekids android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE [allow|ignore|deny]`, not `adb shell pm [grant|revoke] com.kaspersky.safekids  android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE` (though the `android` may have to be replaced with `Manifest`) as `BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE` is a signature permission. For completeness, for Admin, it's `android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN`.

Comment: "The app uses the Device Administrator permission. The app uses Accessibility services." <- That would explain some of its capabilities, at least.

Comment: @MikeM. Can Device Administrators ignore revoked permissions?

Comment: I have no idea; never used it.

Comment: Also, even then, I looked at the permissions that Device Admin Apps have, and none of the permissions look like what Kaspersky is able to do.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "ignore revoked permissions", but the only capabilities you mention in the question are detecting when the child might "open an app, open anything related to its settings, search something banned on Google and Youtube", which are all likely possible with an Accessibility Service (though probably quite tedious to accomplish generally).

Comment: I said that in my question that when I revoked SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, the app is still able to display over the screens, which I thought was the permission is used. Of course, in the light of the comments, that is most likely not true, so I guess it can be ignored.

Comment: Oh, OK. I misread that part of your question. I see what you were asking, then, in your comment. I don't really know. The whole system overlay and permission thing is a complete rat's nest, as far as I'm concerned. Its behavior varies between versions, as does the actual granting of the permission, which also depends on where you installed the app from? I dunno. I try to avoid it altogether, these days, unless it's for a personal app.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks to your observation, I found the exact permission (I also learned that `appops` basically acts as `sudo` compared to `pm`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to narrow down the exact permission used -- using ADB OTG (I didn't have a computer near me, so I used my spare Pixel) I did `appops set com.kaspersky.safekids BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE ignore` (I belive `deny` would work too). Restarted it, and no more pop up. Changed the `ignore` to `allow`, then rebooted, and it worked again.